# Error installing sass on windows

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems

I'm trying to install `sass` with ruby but nothing happens and this message appears:

```
ERROR: Loading command: install (ArgumentError) unknown encoding name - CP720
ERROR: While executing gem ... (NoMethodError) undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

ruby version: 2.3.1 gem version: 2.5.1 windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `koala` or `scout` instead of the sass command line compiler

Answer (score 0):

first type in cmd : chcp 1252 , now you can install sass whit :gem install sass

Answer (score 0):

If you have this: `ERROR:  Loading command: install (ArgumentError)`
go to `C:\Ruby27-x64\lib\ruby\2.7.0\win32\registry.rb`
 and replace this line of code:
`LOCALE = Encoding.find(Encoding.locale_charmap)` to this one 
`LOCALE = Encoding::UTF_8`